# Get rid of values that pollute (or obfuscate) aggregate statistics

Tags: outliers, aggregation

I consider myself a beginner in statistical analysis, and I want some advice on a problem that I have encountered in a data analysis task.

I am monitoring a system's latency for producing results, when different methods are used for one of the system's components. To that end, I have several processes reporting latency every 1 sec and in the end I end up with multiple log files with the following format:

```
# timestamp, throughput, latency
1458750383262,1115,1680
1458750384265,1118,1553
1458750385266,1460,1279
1458750386270,1317,1024
1458750387270,1705,999
1458750388270,1673,1426
1458750389270,2188,1318
1458750390273,1543,1038
1458750391273,2076,3
1458750392273,1888,3
1458750393273,1896,2
1458750394273,2934,17
1458750395273,3573,27
1458750396274,2177,1289
1458750397274,2636,269
1458750398274,3066,282
1458750399275,3699,9
1458750400276,4009,63
1458750401276,4202,92
1458750402276,4302,342
1458750403276,4488,157
1458750404276,4229,31
1458750405276,4761,4
1458750406276,4327,190
1458750407276,4280,644
1458750408276,3974,710
1458750409276,3854,7
1458750410276,3963,404
1458750411276,4550,237
1458750412276,4260,343
1458750413276,4860,247
1458750414284,4846,244
1458750415284,4131,201
1458750416284,4239,300
1458750417284,4569,415
1458750418284,4310,669
1458750419284,3353,53
1458750420285,4465,667
1458750421285,4266,23
1458750422285,3895,7
1458750423285,4092,209
1458750424285,4029,71
1458750425285,4244,3
1458750426285,4407,202
1458750427285,4825,525
1458750428286,3740,4
1458750429287,3943,4
1458750430287,4468,318
1458750431287,4381,4
1458750432287,2501,4
1458750433288,2489,2
1458750434288,2515,3
1458750435288,2501,2
1458750436289,2500,4
1458750437290,2503,4
1458750438290,2499,3
1458750439290,2499,4
1458750440290,2501,5
1458750441290,2501,4
1458750442290,2496,4
1458750443290,2503,2
1458750444290,2500,4
1458750445290,2496,2
1458750446290,2504,4
1458750447290,2499,4
1458750448290,2498,7
1458750449290,2505,2
1458750450290,2499,4
1458750451291,2502,4
1458750452291,2496,2
...
1458750491300,2502,3
1458750492300,2499,4
1458750493300,2502,2
1458750494300,2500,2
1458750495300,2499,2
1458750496300,2500,3
1458750497300,2502,3
1458750498300,2500,2
1458750499300,2497,3
1458750500301,2501,4
1458750501302,2502,4
1458750502302,2503,4
1458750503302,2500,4
1458750504302,2499,3
1458750505302,2500,4
1458750506302,2502,4
1458750507303,2500,3
```

In order to make a decision on which method achieves the lowest latency, I plot the average latency (along with the standard-error bars) from every data point reported by each process.

Unfortunately, as can be seen from the sample data, after a brief starting period in which the system experiences high latency values (warm up phase), the majority of latency  values are between 1 and 10.

Therefore, I wanted to ask which is a good statistical metric (or graph) to see the actual difference, without considering the initial data points which are polluting my results.

Thanks,
Nick